# Releasing a connection in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm using Rails 2.3.8.

What's the best way to release a connection on a model to another database?

Let's say I have ModelB.establish_connection("server_b")

Would ModelB.remove_connection do the trick?  How would I verify that I've successfully removed the connection?

Answer (score 0):

Looks as though [remove_connection](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#method-c-remove_connection) is what you're looking for.  To verify that you've successfully removed the connection, you could wrap a find method within a rescue block like:

```
begin
  ModelB.find(1)
rescue ConnectionNotEstablished
  # if we're here, then we have no connection, which is good in this case
else
  # if we're here, then we still have a connection, which is bad...
end
```